# What's the point in having AppSettingsReader ask for the value's type and return a no-specific-type object?

Tags: c#, .net, appsettings

I don't understand why the framework exposes 
[AppSettingsReader.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingsreader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), which signature is:

```
public object GetValue(string key, Type type);
```

asks for the type of the setting value, and returns a non casted `object` ?!
What's the point in asking for the type and not exposing a generic type-casted value ?!

I am wondering why they did not "*finish*" the job.

If we are already talking about finishing the job, perhaps the following should be what we would like:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string key, T defaultValue = default(T)) where T : class
{
    object value = _appSettingsReader.GetValue(key, typeof(T));
    T castedValue;
    try
    {
        castedValue = (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        castedValue = defaultValue;
    }

    return castedValue;
}
```

Comment: The `... as T` could simply be `(T)...`.

Comment: I know... I personally think it makes the intention clearer. But this is now being picky... :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: you actually made a good point. There is a _distinction_ between the two, and it's exactly what I was looking for (on a different problem). Casting with "as" requires the generic type to be a class, while using (T) not. In other words, using "as" in the solution meant it precluded struct types, such as double. So the solution was not as generic as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the point in asking for the type and not exposing a generic type-casted value ?!

Well, I guess they wrote that code before the generics era. This method was there since .NET 1.1, so definitely pre-generics.

The point in asking the type is that behind that method, it does convert the value to the right type. It just isn't exposed to the outside world. It has to know how to read the XML and convert that to a specific type.

Of course, they could (and maybe should) rewrite that code so it uses generics. That would benefit us all.

Comment: I know they ask it for a reason - and I guessed they perform a cast in the internals. Considering the pre-generics "era", is there really much gain for such a thing? I mean, the method "spares" you from the casting job ? Not completely...

Comment: It prevents errors since you only have to write the type once instead of twice.

Comment: Well... ok, it's not perfect but they did what was at their hands to do. :-) They should definitely change this, however.